# Intermittent failures receiving interstitial admob ad - TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-x

I am using Google Play Services revision 21.

I have the following activity in my game.  The banner ads work perfectly fine, and the interstitial ads only sometimes appear. The `showInterstitial` method gets called via JNI from my game code which is written in C++, though I don't believe that has any relevance to the problem.

```
public class AppActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity {
        private AdView adView;
        private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER = "my banner id";
        private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL = "my interstitial id"; 
        private static AppActivity _appActivity;
        private static InterstitialAd interstitial;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setupBannerAd();
            setupInterstitial();

            _appActivity = this;
        }

        private void setupBannerAd() {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            int width = getDisplaySize(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()).x;

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("74CF565D181FBE42D5B6C217467E561F")
                .build();

            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            adView.setBackgroundColor(0);
            addContentView(adView,adParams);
        }

        private void setupInterstitial() {
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("74CF565D181FBE42D5B6C217467E561F")
                .build();
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        }

        public static void showInterstitial() {
            _appActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                        interstitial.show();
                    }

                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addTestDevice("74CF565D181FBE42D5B6C217467E561F")
                        .build();
                    //TODO: sometimes this loadAd call fails. why?
                    //set onFailedToReceiveAd listener and do another loadAd?
                    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
                }
            });
        }
        //other methods here
    }
```

Occasionally I will receive the following error when requesting another interstitial ad:

```
!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Could not fetch ad response from ad request service.

android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)

at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.ab.a(SourceFile:101)

at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.s.a(SourceFile:187)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.s.a(SourceFile:164)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(SourceFile:17)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.d.call(SourceFile:29)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.call(SourceFile:49)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
Failed to load ad: 0
```

I've tried rearranging the code quite a bit, but nothing I've tried changes the outcome.  For example, I've tried using an `AdListener` and attaching it to the `InterstitialAd` object and overriding the `onAdClosed` method and from there trying to request the next ad.

Does anybody have any ideas?